# AJAX POST Not Returning php mysql ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to get data from the database using ajax to insert it in other  element but the post data not passing to **get-data.php**
so what the reason can be and the solution
[image]
[image: passed data shown here but no resposns]

**addBuilding.php**

```
<?php
require_once("./dbConfig.php");
$selectIL = "SELECT * FROM  iller ";
$selectIL = $db->prepare($selectIL);
$selectIL->execute();
$res = $selectIL->get_result();
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="pp" id="cites">
        <option value="">-select state-</option>
        <?php
        while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
            <option value="<?= $row['id'] ?>"><?= $row['il_adi'] ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <select name="district" id="district">
         <option value="">-select district-</option>
    </select>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="getdata.js"></script>
```

**getdata.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#cites").change(function() {
        if ( $("#cites").val()!="") {
            $("#district").prop("disabled",false);
        }else  {
            $("#district").prop("disabled",true);
        }
        var city = $("#cites").val(); 
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",    
            url:"get-data.php",
            data:$(city).serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                $("#district").append(result); 
            }
        });

    });
});
```

**get-data.php**
I can see the form data in network inspection put no data passing to **get-data.php**

```
<?php
require_once("./dbConfig.php"); 

if (isset($_POST['pp'])) {
   
    $cites = $_POST['cites'];
    $selectIlce = "SELECT * FROM  ilceler where il_id=? ";
    $selectIlce = $db->prepare($selectIlce);
    $selectIlce->bind_param("i", $cites);
    $selectIlce->execute();
    $res = $selectIlce->get_result();
?>
    <?php
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
        <option value="<?= $row['id'] ?>"><?= $row['ilce_adi'] ?></option>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `var city = $("#cites").val();` - that gets the currently selected option value. `data:$(city).serialize()` - what element on your page do you think you are selecting here now, with `$(city)` ...?

Answer (score 1):

You need to echo the results in get-data.php

```
<?php
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
        echo "<option value='". $row["id"]."'>".$row['ilce_adi']."</option>";
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: not exactly because the post doesn't go to ger-data.php I tried print post array using print_r function its returns a null array

Comment: try to give proper address in ajax, your url can't be just get-data.php....? it should be something like this http://localhost/project-name/get-data.php

Answer (score 0):

1- Get data by serialize from form:

```
$("form").serialize()
```

2- Add dataType: "json" to ajax option:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",    
    url:"get-data.php",
    data:$(city).serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
        $("#district").append(result); 
    }
});
```